# Maven does not generate snapshot

Tags: eclipse, maven

My maven project in Eclipse suddenly does not generate the snapshot folder and war file anymore, although mvn package command will still trigger a compiler action and build class file to target/class folder, but no snapshot war file and folder will be generated to target folder. I have config in pom.xml and saw "Building xxx 1.0-SNAPSHOT" output, but no war file or SNAPSHOT folder come out of that. Has anyone encountered this before? I use Mars 4.5.2 and on Mac OS X 10.10.5

Comment: Where should this SNAPSHOT folder being generated ? You should call Maven on command line to test such things instead of inside of Eclipse...

Comment: I have config in pom.xml and run mvn package command in command line, and saw output like "Building XXX 1.0-SNAPSHOT" but no war file or SNAPSHOT folder is generated after that

Comment: Run maven with the `-X` option to enable debugging. Save the results and search them for the reason it's not generated or the location where it gets placed.

Comment: What kind of packaging have you defined in your pom file? The line `<packaging>..</packaging>` in your pom file? If you haven't defined it the default is `jar`...

Comment: <packaging>war</packaging> is what I'm using

Comment: I might found the reason for this. I'm writing some unit test case for REST API in this project and got failure in test. I comment out the case that leads to the failure and SNAPSHOT folder and war file appears. So this is the convention of Maven: if some unit test case fail, the target war and snapshot will not be generated?

Answer (score 1):

Check if pom.xml exists or not. If it exists
Right click -> Maven ->Update Project.
This worked for me.